# codeigniter.php is not responding to my source code

Tags: php, codeigniter

I downloaded my source code from the Cpanel and I deployed it in a local machine using XAMPP. When opening my project(`index.php`), it displays a blank page. So, I added the below code to `index.php`:

```
echo "before calling";
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
echo "after calling";
```

Then "before calling" is displayed on the output page, but "after calling" is not showing. I'm not getting any idea what to do, could someone please help?

Comment: what happends if you do a echo BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

Comment: your files are corrupt. Download them again from the CI website: http://www.codeigniter.com/download